# Change size of svg-element dynamically while moving an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I got some moveable items in a svg-element as shown here:

**JSfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/xfvf4/37/

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="300" width="300" version="1.1"></div>
```

As you can see, the items can be moved to the edge of the svg. I tried to achieve that the svg gets bigger as moving an element to the edge. i.e. if you move a rechtangle to an area near an edge (i.e. 20px), the svg gets bigger as you are moving the item.